# "Handle" Data Type Equivalent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, handle

I am reading the documentation for [MoPaQ](http://sfsrealm.hopto.org/inside_mopaq/chapter4.htm) and trying to convert the functions over to Delphi because some of the data types mentioned in the documentation do not directly match the ones in Delphi.

This is the function I am having troubles with:

```
HANDLE WINAPI MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(LPCSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwHashTableSize);
```

In Delphi, I have converted it as:

```
function MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(lpFileName: Char, CreationDisposition, dwHashTableSize: LongWord); external 'lmpqapi.dll';
```

---

I am missing the return type for my function which I believe is `HANDLE` (according to the documentation). If that is the case, what is the Delphi equivalent for the `HANDLE` data type?

Comment: Return a THandle, lpFileName would be PChar I guess.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Thank you! Delphi is giving me an error expecting a closing bracket at the very first comma of that function. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a `;` between parameters.

Comment: LPCSTR is a PAnsiChar, sorry. XE2 has that one defined.

Comment: there are tools for automatic conversion H -> PAS. You seems quite a novice in Delphi to make such typos. Then perhaps do auto-conversion instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent would be something along these lines:

```
function MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(lpFileName: LPCSTR; 
  dwCreattionDisposition,
  dwHasTableSize: DWord): THandle; stdcall; external 'lmpqapi.dll';
```

<strike>Note that you'll have to find out if MoPacQ is Unicode-aware or not; if it's not, change the definition of `lpFileName` to `PAnsiChar` instead.</strike>

Remy points out in his comment below that Delphi maps `LPCSTR` to the proper `PAnsiChar` type on all versions, so you should use it that way.

Comment: Hi Ken, what purpose does the `stdcall` serve?

Comment: It replaces the `WINAPI`, which tells the function in what order to push the parameters on the stack. It's documented in the Delphi help file [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions). The Windows API (which is the most frequent standard used on Windows, obviously) uses `stdcall`.

Comment: `LPCSTR` always maps to `PAnsiChar` in every Delphi version. Use `PAnsiChar`, or even `LPCSTR` as-is, in the declaration, do not use `PChar`: `function MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(lpFileName: LPCSTR; dwCreationDisposition, dwHashTableSize: DWORD): THandle; stdcall; external ...;`

Comment: @Remy: Thanks. Didn't have a chance to check that first. Code updated to reflect your comment (with attribution to you for the correction).